# Как программно узнать порт, по которому движется пакет?

Tags: c++, сниффер

Добрый день. Написала программу сниффера, работающего в "неразборчивом" режиме (Promiscuous mode). Как можно узнать номер порта, по которому приходит тот или иной пакет?

Comment: Я с вами совсем запутался. Напишите более подробно, какого рода пакеты вы пытаетесь отловить, приведите пример кода. И ваш последний комментарий заставил меня усомниться, что подразумеваете под портом: физический интерфейс компьютера или порт транспортного уровня OSI? Если второе, то он есть не у всех пакетов.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью чего вы писали сниффер? [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/default.htm)?

[Как получить список всех портов](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html).

Когда вы начинаете захват с помощью функции [pcap_loop](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#ga6bcb7c5c59d76ec16b8a699da136b5de), вы указываете конкретный интерфейс, с которого осуществляется захват. Пакеты, пришедшие на другие интерфейсы, не захватываются и не попадают в вашу callback-функцию. Самый простой способ - сделайте несколько callback-функций, по одной функции на каждый порт. По тому, в какую функцию пришёл вновь захваченный пакет, вы сможете определить, на какой порт он пришёл.

Comment: Нет, с помощью режима SIO_RCVALL, так что вариант для WinPcap не подойдёт.

Comment: @Махинс, напишите это в вопросе. Это важная информация.

Comment: Я указала, что использую "неразборчивый" режим. Это он и есть, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: @Махинс, я вас не совсем понял. Судя по документации, функция `ioctlsocket` всего лишь управляет состоянием сокета, а никак не отлавливает пакеты. С помощью сокета можно *косвенно* определить, на каком интерфейсе принят пакет, сравнивая ip-адрес интерфейса с адресом отправителя, если отправитель находится в этой же сети.

Comment: Ага, уже `SIO_RCVALL`. Ладно. Так или иначе вы работаете с обычными windows-сокетами. Сокеты не предоставляют информацию о физических интерфейсах компьютера, поэтому вам придётся анализировать адреса отправителя-получателя.

Comment: А как можно вытянуть эту информацию из адресов отправителя и получателя?

Comment: Информацию об отправителе я выводу следующим образом:
printf("Source: ");
sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_src;
printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));
printf("\r\n");
Где iph_src - просто набор бит, а мне нужно sa1.sin_port где-то взять получается.